# Browser fails to compute correct page height. On manual window resize, the size suddenly changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

My current project was till today totally composed of styles DIVs. Anything was just fine. No problems.

To make the **content center** in the browser windows, I added this [I'm aware of the fact, that this isn't beautiful]:

```
<table style="width: 100%; min-width: 1000px;">
<tr>
<td >
  <div id="mainBox">
    ...
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The style of `mainBox` is like so:

```
position:relative;
width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
```

After this change, the behavior of the site changed:

- All pages render
- Some pages stop to render at a certain vertical point and some stuff is outside the lower border
- The scroll bars do not adapt to the stuff below the lower border. Thus, I can't reach the lower border

As soon as I manually resize the browser window, the browser corrects this problem.

I verified the behavior in Safari and Chrome. **Firefox seems to render fine.**

**I'm lost. Could anybody propose hints, how to fix this?** WebKit bug?

PS: The site includes jQuery and jQueryUI, but only one script generated page includes an accordion.

**UPDATE 2003-05-09**

In replaced the TABLE with a DIV element and the page renders just fine:

```
<div style="width: 100%; min-width: 1000px;">
 <div id="mainBox">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I'd still be happy to learn, the table element didn't render correctly, I'm going to keep the question open and probably track down the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Are you able to duplicate this issue in a jsfiddle?  We will probably need to see your other elements and css to diagnose the issue.

Comment: So you are just going for horizontal centering (since I see no heights set anywhere in your code)? Well, you could’ve had that much easier without misusing a table …

Comment: My above code is incomplete. I'm aware of the misuse! In fact, the table was (due to other aspects) only meant as an intermediate solution. Hm, well, did I say intermediate solution? I should call it technical dept :-(

Comment: @CBroe ... and misuse of markup is by far the smallest problem I currently have to solve ;-)